# Select Group by from Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table `users` like this:

```
id user refid
1  a    null
2  b    1
3  c    1
4  d    2
5  f    3
```

I need to select the users, grouping by refid and the count of each refid for each user.  For example,

```
id    user count
1      a     2
2      b     1
3      c     1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT user, refid, count(*) cnt FROM `users` group by refid
```

However, this gives me the wrong user for each value.  How can I get the correct user for each value?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. What does user "a" have to do with refid "1", user "b" have to do with refid "2" and such? In yor table user "a" have a refid of "null" and user "b" has a refid of "1".  Why do you expect them to be matched the way you show in your expected results? Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MikeBrant I agree with you. However, I think the OP meant `id` instead of `refid` in the sample output. Then it would make sense, as the OP would be looking for the amount of referrals per user (for the ones that have at least one).

Comment: @MostyMostacho is correct about the id, i made edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for. Basically, you're missing a join there.

```
select u1.id, u1.user, count(u1.id) cnt from mlm_users u1
join mlm_users u2 on u1.id = u2.refid
group by u1.id, u1.user
```

This will return the id, user and the amount of referrals each of them have (only for the ones that have at least one referral).

Comment: what if i want to return both those that have referrals and those that don't have as 0, i tried this `SELECT u1 . * , count( u1.id ) cnt FROM mlm_users u1 LEFT JOIN mlm_users u2 ON u1.id = u2.refid GROUP BY u1.id` which was returning for those that have zero as 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the user and refid

```
SELECT user, refid, count(*) cnt FROM `mlm_users` group by user,redid
```